# Can I use any load balancer service with unmanaged vps from any reseller?

Tags: load-balancing, vps

I bought my vps from vpscheap.net. How can I install load balancers for them? Is there any load balancing service available for this type of configuration? Or should i build my own load balancer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load balancer of what services ?

If you mean load balancer of http / https, you can use example nginx to make this (example: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html ) .

Comment: Yes. Already decided on nginx load balancing. Thanks.